# CSRFToken attribute is missing in HttpSession when migrating from CSRFGuard 3.1.0 to 4.0.0

Tags: maven, tomcat, csrf

I migrated from CSRFGuard 3.1.0 to 4.0.0 for my project, i have included csrf-session-extension and csrf-jsp-tag dependencies as they are required for migration. After making neccessary changes in properties, I can able to build the maven application and deploy it in tomcat server. However, after requesting data from database, i receive following errors:

> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke Servlet.service()
> for servlet [services] in context with path threw exception
> **com.proj.libs.core.common.exception.ValidationError: Validation Error:
> Invalid CSRF token.**
> at com.server.security.CsrfFilter.validateCsrfToken(CsrfFilter.java:68)
> at com.server.security.CsrfFilter.doFilter(CsrfFilter.java:47)

I found out that exception occurs due to my HttpSession not containing CSRFToken attribute hence the validation fails. It occurs only when I start sing CSRFGuard 4.0.0 in project from 3.1.0 . How to resolve this issue?

My property file:

```
org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenName=OWASP-CSRFTOKEN
org.owasp.csrfguard.SessionKey=OWASP-CSRFTOKEN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From csrfguard 4.x.x onwards, we don't have csrftoken stored in httpsession so we have to store these tokens in somewhere. We can configure the storage option in property file. I have chosen InMemoryImplementagtion method. Here our session tokens are stored in the memeory. Hence, we can access the session tokens using from the memory storage using the session key.